# why cisco VPNC work on the second time each time and not on the first time

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, cisco

I use the vpnc ( cisco VPN that installed on linux red-hat 6.X )

and the vpnc.conf file look like this

```
 more /etc/vpnc.conf 
 ## generated by pcf2vpnc
 IPSec ID Comvwde
 IPSec gateway 217.118.6.7
 IPSec secret eJ9^DyiE

 IKE Authmode psk

 ## To add your DUMMY and password,
 ## use the following lines:
 Xauth username 
 Xauth password
```

according to this **vpnc.conf** no need login or password

but when I run the vpnc ( vpnc work only on the second time each time that I run it )

please advice why this happened ?

**example**

```
  vpnc
  vpnc: no response from target
```

**on the second time**

```
  vpnc
  VPNC started in background (pid: 27897)...


  vpnc-disconnect
  Terminating vpnc daemon (pid: 27897)
```

**and again**

```
  vpnc
  vpnc: no response from target


  vpnc
  VPNC started in background (pid: 27897)...
```

**Network configuration on my linux machine:**

```
 ifconfig -a|grep inet
      inet addr:128.102.183.102  Bcast:128.102.183.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:feba:80b/64 Scope:Link
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      inet addr:10.150.27.18  P-t-P:10.150.27.18  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet addr:10.70.70.176  P-t-P:10.70.70.176  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet addr:10.150.27.33  P-t-P:10.150.27.33  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet addr:10.150.27.34  P-t-P:10.150.27.34  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet addr:10.150.27.50  P-t-P:10.150.27.50  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet addr:10.150.27.13  P-t-P:10.150.27.13  Mask:255.255.255.255
```